# How to prevent adding duplicate id on a page in a multi-page html document?

Tags: jquery-mobile

I have a header.jsp that I am including on all the pages to display header and logo of my project. It has a link that opens up panel.
//header.jsp

```
<div data-role="header">
<a href="#menuPanel" data-icon="bars" data-rel="panel">Menu</a>


 <div data-role="panel" id="menuPanel" data-position-fixed="true" data-display="overlay" >My menu</div>
</div>
```

Now I am using a multi page html document. The header will be included on all the div's with data-role=page.

```
<div data-role="page" id="page1">
//include header
</div>
<div data-role="page" id="page2">
//include header here
</div>
```

My doubt is my header.jsp has a panel with id="menuPanel". Two div with the same id will be included twice on my html page. Even on clicking the link we might get unepected results.How can I resolve this and save my project from including two div with the same id in DOM. I want to keep header as a separate file. 
Can my panel be opened in some other way apart from using id. Please suggest some solution

Comment: use external _header_ and _panel_; dont repeat yourself, add them one time only,

Answer (score 0):

Change your header to use `class` and not `id`, and link to `#`:

```
<div data-role="header">
    <a href="#" class="menuButton" data-icon="bars" data-rel="panel">Menu</a>
    <div data-role="panel" class="menuPanel" data-position-fixed="true" data-display="overlay" >My menu</div>
</div>
```

And add some JavaScript to open/close the menu panel relative to current page:

```
$(document).on("click", ".menuButton", function(event)
{
    var pageID = $(this).closest("[data-role=page]").attr("id");
    $("#" + pageID + " .menuPanel").panel("toggle");
});
```

**[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ry5yW/)**

Comment: why to make things more complicated? This will result in the same, since a _Multi-Page Model_ is used, whether you use a class or an id.

Comment: question doesn't clarify how the header is included; while duplication is despicable, without other information I cannot suggest how to avoid it

Comment: @Sga : Thanks. Its a java web application.The header is specified in a jsp file that will be included within a div that has a data-role header. Both the panels will perform same work. So does using a class instead of id will resolve the problem? Doing $(".menuPanel") in page2 won't call panel in page2?

Comment: I fixed the code with the right selector and added a JSFiddle. Anyway: please try refactoring your code to avoid duplication of header elements